# Text message abbreviation decoder: NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I need help developing my text message abbreviation decoder I'm trying to put together. The first part of the program should do this: "If a user's input string matches a known text message abbreviation, output the unabbreviated form, else output: Unknown. Support two abbreviations: LOL -- laughing out loud, and IDK -- I don't know." Then: "Expand to also decode these abbreviations. BFF -- best friends forever, IMHO -- in my humble opinion and TMI -- too much information.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgAbbreviation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String textMsg = "";
        {
            String BFF = "best friends forever";
            String IMHO = "in my humble opinion";
            String TMI = "too much information";
            String LOL = "laughing out loud";
            String IDK = "i don't care";

            System.out.println("Input an abbreviation:" + " ");

            textMsg = input.next();

            if (textMsg.compareTo("LOL") == 0) {
                System.out.println(LOL);
            } else if (textMsg.compareTo("IDK") == 0) {
                System.out.println(IDK);
            } else if (textMsg.compareTo("BFF") == 0) {
                System.out.println(BFF);
            } else if (textMsg.compareTo("IMHO") == 0) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
        at TextMsgAbbreviation.main(TextMsgAbbreviation.java:17)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code run well for me,  in which case you've got the error?

Comment: A `NoSuchElementException` in this context is indicating that there was no input from `System.in` - how do you give your input to the program?

Comment: @Papershine If he had closed `System.in` he would get a different exception.

Comment: @takintoolong No extra curly braces here. Which ones did you think they were? and how would that cause a runtime exception?

Answer (score 1):

The values displayed 862 1371 17 need to be typed into the input box.Below is working code for the problem.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TextMsgDecoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

     String userInput;
    System.out.println("Enter text:");
    userInput = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);
    if(userInput.indexOf("BFF") != -1) {
        System.out.println("BFF: best friend forever");
    }
    if(userInput.indexOf("IDK") != -1) {
        System.out.println("IDK: I don't know");
    }
    if(userInput.indexOf("JK") != -1) {
        System.out.println("JK: just kidding");
    }
   if(userInput.indexOf("TMI") != -1) {
        System.out.println("TMI: too much information");
   }
  if(userInput.indexOf("TTYL") != -1) {
        System.out.println("TTYL: talk to you later");
   }
```

}
}

Comment: @CommunityBot I know you're a bot but there is nothing unclear about this answer whatsoever. The OP needs to provide some *input*, as stated in the first line of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--), the `next()` method throws a `NoSuchElementException` when there aren't any more tokens available to be read. So, it is recommended to call the `hasNext()` method before calling the `next()` method in `Scanner` class to make sure that there is a token available to be read. So, try something like below :

```
if(input.hasNext()) {
    textMsg = input.next();
}
```

On a side-note, from Java 7 onwards, the `switch` statements can take a `String` input, so you may try using that in your code. In my personal opinion, it will be more readable than using the multiple if-else loops.
An example :

```
    switch(textMsg) {
        case "LOL" : System.out.println(LOL);
                     break;
        case "IDK" : System.out.println(IDK);
                     break;
        case "BFF" : System.out.println(BFF);
                     break;
        case "IMHO": System.out.println(IMHO);
                      break;
        default    : System.out.println("Unknown");
   }
```